# Easiest way to check for ZXing support?

Tags: android, zxing

I want an app to use [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) barcode scanner. I think the [ScanningViaIntent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) is a good way for this app to integrate the scanning. However, I would like to runtime know if the user is able to use this app or not. Is there a simple way to do this? Or should I now and then check their [AndroidManifest.xml](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml) to see what the required features for a device are + check if the user has Play Store installed?

EDIT: Just to make it clear; I wanted to in **code** know if there was **device support**. I know the ScanningViaIntent handles the app not being installed very well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you should check if the user has a camera, or maybe other things like auto-focus. For some of my projects I had to integrate ZXing directly into the project to avoid this kind of problems.

But after all, some cases just telling the user that he must have a minimum requirement to use the scanning function can be enough ^^

Comment: I think you are right. I've added the code I'm using for checking this now. 'cause I would like to be able to tell the user what's supported and not. It's a bad user experience to not find the app in the Play Store just because your tablet doesn't have a away faced camera.

Answer (score 2):

The ZXing team have provided a small library of code to handle this scenario elegantly, including prompting the user to download the ZXing barcode scanner if they do not already have it installed.

The details and download link can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent):

I realise such linking is frowned upon here, but other than wholly duplicating the information from the linked site and posting the full content of the provided library, I couldn't see how else to adequately answer the question. Any advice on how to would be appreciated

EDIT: Apologies, I should have checked the links in the OPs question and seen that he was already aware of the IntentIntegrator code libary for ZXing

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do something like `initiateScan` method in the `ZXing` client

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java

it prompts to download ZXing if it's not installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing. At least until I find a better way. :)

```
/**
 * Convenience method for checking for ZXing app support. Requirements found
 * in http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml 
 * and
 * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java
 * .
 * 
 * @return boolean true if app is supported, false if not.
 */
protected boolean hasSupportForZxing() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    if(!packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){ // ZXing required away faced camera
        return false;
    }
    if(!packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SCREEN_LANDSCAPE)){ // ZXing requires landscape mode
        if(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SCREEN_PORTRAIT)){ // PackageManager doc states that if both landscape and portrait support is missing then both are probably supported (compatibility reasons)
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(!isMarketUrisHandled()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected boolean isMarketUrisHandled() {
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=dummy"));
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(marketIntent, 0);
    return resolveInfos.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Zxing has now (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml?r=2398) removed the requirement for an away faced camera. So the check for FEATURE_CAMERA should be removed.

Comment: zxing has now (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/diff?spec=svn2543&r=2502&format=side&path=/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml&old_path=/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml&old=2433) added requirement for touchscreen to exclude Google TV, so a check for this feature should be added.